# Escape double quotes in JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a real brain-block here for something which seems too simple. How can I escape double-quoted strings in a single-quoted JSON string:

```
var json = '{ "quote": ""Hello World", he said." }';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

I've tried:

- `'{ "quote": "\"Hello World\", he said." }'`
- `'{ "quote": "\\\"Hello World\\\", he said." }'`
- `'{ "quote": """Hello World"", he said." }'`

Each of which results in various syntax errors. Expected output is:

```
var obj = {
  "quote": "\"Hello World\", he said."
};
```

Comment: What about var json = '{ "quote": "\\"Hello World\\", he said." }'; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want

```
{ "quote": "\"Hello World\", he said." }
```

then notice you have to escape the backslashes only, because `"` has no especial meaning within single quotes:

```
'{ "quote": "\\"Hello World\\", he said." }'
```

Comment: Your explanation clarifies what's happening here so you earned the tick :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong... but since you ecpect the output to be

```
"quote": "\"Hello World\", he said."
```

You should try it by maskin it like this:

```
'{ "quote": "\\"Hello World\\", he said." }'
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried

```
var json = '{ "quote": "\\"Hello World\\", he said." }';
```

Works.